# Image upload format

Tags: php

I have a form for uplading photo. That photo should be either `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, or `.bmp`. When I am trying to upload an image, or photo, then it will stored in a temporary folder and the name of the image/photo should be the user_id of the form. Till yet am done..

But my problem is that,

1. only the `.jpg` file is uploaded and displayed and when I try to upload the other type, then it will stored in temporary folder, and it does not displayed.

Comment: Can you share the appropriate code?

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Comment: Show us what you are doing currently.

Comment: Note that PHP's image processing functions can not handle BMPs.

Answer (score -1):

***Just Try with the following Example :***

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: -1, code dumps are not answers.  Please explain what this code does and how it helps the OP.  Further, this code is *horrible*.  It trusts the user's MIME type *and* trusts their filename.

Comment: @BenilaAnoop Can you post your code i'll fix it, it might be helpful for me to understand the problem.

Comment: @Benila Can you give the up vote and acceptance of my answer.